# Multiplexer bandwidth limit (Datasheet decryption) for two external clock on STM32

Tags: stm32, clock, multiplexer, bandwidth

I would like to have the possibility to select between two main clock  on my STM32. Both clock are single ended, 3V3 LVCMOS output. First clock is a 19.2 MHz TCXO, and second clock is a variable clock generator at 10 MHz max. The STM32 is powered  at 3V3 and HSE is in pass through.

I found a chip like [74AUP1G157](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74AUP1G157.pdf) but I 'm not sure if I read the datasheet correctly about bandwidth limit (max frequency I can pass through this chip).

I will put one clock on **I0**, the second on **I1**, the STM32 clock input pin (OSCIN) on **Y** and I will toggle the **S** input with GPIO.  (I have no problem configuring STM32 internal PLL, switching back MSI, etc...)

[image: Verity table]

I want to be sure what is the [74AUP1G157](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74AUP1G157.pdf) bandwidth and more generally understand how to get the bandwidth limit on an "multiplexer" component.

On this kind of device I only see a time dependent parameter called "Propagation delay" (Tpd) depend on output capacitance. For example if I take the worst case output capacitance CL = 30 pF at 3V3 I can get Tpd = 6 ns (25°C)

[image: Propagation delay at 30 pF capacitance]

To get the maximum bandwidth in this context, I would like to do :

```
F = 1 / Tpd  
F = 1 / 6 ns
F = 166.7 MHz
```

I probably need to get a security factor like 2 or more :

```
Fmax = 0.4 x F  
Fmax = 0.4 x 166.7 MHz  
Fmax = 66 MHz
```

With this chip, I can probably safely pass **66 MHz** clock signal through this multiplexer. (at 25°C, Vcc = 3V3 and track impedance between this chip and STM32 dont exceed 30 pF)

Is my reasoning correct or did I not understand anything about multiplexer bandwidth ?
(In case of NO, can you help me to understand how to find the bandwidth limit of a multiplexer ?)